# Django Import-Export: Admin interface "TypeError at /"

Tags: python, django

I am trying to figure out how to use Django Import-Export,

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-import-export

by reading the docs

https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html#admin-integration

### Admin Integration:

The gap between the example code and its resulting photo that follows, seems to be vast for my elementary python knowledge.

I have managed to code the following:

geographical_system/**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Regional_Units(models.Model):
    regional_unit = models.CharField(
        max_length=64, verbose_name=_(u'Regional Units'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.regional_unit)
```

geographical_system/**resources.py**:

```
from import_export import resources
from geographical_system.models import Regional_Units
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin


class Regional_Units_Resource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta(object):
        model = Regional_Units


class Regional_Units_Resource_Admin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resouce_class = Regional_Units_Resource # Why originally commented out?
    #pass #Why pass?
```

geographical_system/**admin.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from geographical_system.models import Regional_Units
from geographical_system.resources import Regional_Units_Resource_Admin


admin.site.register(Regional_Units)
admin.site.register(Regional_Units_Resource_Admin)  # **Improvising here**, otherwise nothing would happen
```

### Resulting Error

Of course, my improvisation `admin.site.register(Regional_Units_Resource_Admin)` resulted in the following message when visiting

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/geographical_system/regional_units/`

```
TypeError at /admin/geographical_system/regional_units/

'RenameBaseModelAdminMethods' object is not iterable

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/geographical_system/regional_units/
Django Version:     1.6
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

'RenameBaseModelAdminMethods' object is not iterable

Exception Location:     /home/flyer/.virtualenvs/rara/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py in register, line 71
Python Executable:  /home/flyer/.virtualenvs/rara/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.5
Python Path:    

['/home/flyer/02/rara',
 '/home/flyer/.virtualenvs/rara/lib64/python27.zip',
 '/home/flyer/.virtualenvs/rara/lib64/python2.7',
 '/home/flyer/.virtualenvs/rara/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/flyer/.virtualenvs/rara/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/flyer/.virtualenvs/rara/lib64/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/flyer/.virtualenvs/rara/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/flyer/.virtualenvs/rara/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

### Questions

- Why is this error appearing?
- How could I end - up into this beautiful admin interface where Import and Export options are enabled?

Comment: You might want to register that against a class. Try: `admin.site.register(Regional_Units, Regional_Units_Resource_Admin) `

Comment: Tough documentation for my level, thanx!

Comment: Just one more caveat.  Make sure that order of class is right.  You want to use Regional_Units first then Regional_Units_Resource_Admin.  I had it the other way around, which showed me this error and had no idea why.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although I'm not familiar with this particular app, what you should do is replace

```
admin.site.register(Regional_Units)
admin.site.register(Regional_Units_Resource_Admin)
```

with

```
admin.site.register(Regional_Units, Regional_Units_Resource_Admin)
```

and if everything else is ok it should work. The admin `register()` method expects the Model as first argument and (optionally) a ModelAdmin class (or subclass) as second argument.

Sidenote: since you're just starting with python/django try to comply with the conventions. This means do not use `_` between words in class Names (i.e. RegionalUnits is a suitable name) and try to place `ModelAdmin` declarations right inside the admin.py module (i.e. `RegionalUnitsResourceAdmin` should be declared in admin.py rather than being imported).

Comment: Thanx for the conventions, advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you shoule replace

```
admin.site.register(Regional_Units_Resource_Admin)
```

with

```
admin.site.register(Regional_Units, Regional_Units_Resource_Admin)
```